# No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000000a ? android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-resources

I have been searching stack and have found no help regarding this topic

```
03-06 11:37:02.448: W/ResourceType(14147): No package identifier when getting value for    resource number 0x0000000a
03-06 11:37:02.448: D/AndroidRuntime(14147): Shutting down VM
03-06 11:37:02.448: W/dalvikvm(14147): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x41d1b438)
03-06 11:37:02.448: I/Process(14147): Sending signal. PID: 14147 SIG: 9
03-06 11:37:02.448: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 11:37:02.448: E/AndroidRuntime(14147): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sliderexample/com.example.sliderexample.FragmentControllers.LeftRightSliderFragmentController}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xa
```

I am including a library, and the LeftRightSliderFragment class has a base class that is apart of that project library. Do I need to some how include the project library in the main project android manifest?

If so how do I do this I can't seem to find this on google.

Comment: Clean the project then build it.

Comment: tried deleting the bin and gen, and cleaned and rebuilt.